# Howto Disable Popup from MSVC Runtime Libraray on HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windows-7, jenkins, popup

I have a c++ application, that is corruption the heap. When I execute it, I get a popup from the "Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Libraray" with the title "Debug Error!" and the error message "HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: ...".

I have a jenkins running several jobs. When this error occurs, this popup shows up and the execution blocks, blocking my slave.

My question: How can I change the behavior of windows and/or the run time library, so the offending application just gets aborted and this fact gets recorded on stdout? I have seen some answers using drwtsn.exe, but this tool does not exists for newer windows. Also disable the Windows Error Reporting did not work as expected.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think that if you build your application in *Release* mode, then it will yield the desired behavior.

Comment: Thanks barak. This might help, but it does not solve my problem. What I want is to have automated debug builds and test execution  in a continuous integration process without the need of user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the offending application, call `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter` to call e.g. `abort` so the dialogs are not displayed. For details see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680634(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks Wojtek. I cannot call abort(), because this will also trigger the popup. I can catch the exception and exit(), but this is not yet what I am looking for, as other libraries I depend on, also do call abort (e.g. the boost library).